# Display the fetch data with spaces or break - PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I want to display the data with some spaces or break lines. Can someone help me about this? Im using `textarea` for the news content in adding and editing. And the data type for my news content is `text`.

i the content want to display like this.
[image]

here is my work. As you can see there is no break there
[image]

here is the code for fetching the data.

```
<?php
    include_once('connection.php');
     $newsid = $_GET['newsid'];

     $sql ="SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_id = '$newsid'";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     $title = $row['news_title'];
     $date = $row['news_date'];
     $content = $row['news_content'];
     $newsimage = $row['news_image'];
         }         
    ?>

 <img src="<?php echo $newsimage; ?>" alt="court" style="width:100%; height:430px; ">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="fix midbar">
                  <div class="viewnews">
                        <h3><?php echo $title; ?> </h3>
                         <p>Date posted: <?php echo $date; ?></p>
                         <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>
                  </div>
               </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **nl2br**

**nl2br** — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

**Description**

```
string nl2br ( string $string [, bool $is_xhtml = true ] )
```

Returns string with `<br /> or <br>` inserted before all newlines `(\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).`

Comment: What if there is no <br> when i add? just a simple cut or space.

Comment: the new line character will be there i guess. Just give it a try. You don't need to add.

Comment: @nethken: Well, somehow you need to separate the sentences, and the best leverage is the line break. If the text doesn't have line breaks, that's it. It will become one long wall of text. But when you paste from Word or any other app, which has paragraphs, they will be pasted with line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Break the content on line breaks. You can use PHP's `nl2br` function:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $title = $row['news_title'];
    $date = $row['news_date'];
    $content = nl2br($row['news_content']);
    $newsimage = $row['news_image'];
}
```

`nl2br` will replace all line breaks with HTML line break (`<br>`) tags.

However, this is only a part solution, as it will only add one line break, which would look like this:

> Text one text one text one 
>   Text two Text  Text

Obviously, this is not exactly what you want. You want this:

> Text one text one text one
>
> Text two Text  Text

To have more control on this, split the `$content` on line breaks, and wrap each part in span tags.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $title = $row['news_title'];
    $date = $row['news_date'];
    $newsimage = $row['news_image'];
    $content = $row['news_content'];

    // splits the content on line breaks
    $content_array = explode("\r\n", $content);

    // go through each item and wrap them into a span 
    // (you can style it later with css, if you wish)
    foreach ($content_array as &$item) {
        $item = '<span class="news_item">'.$item.'</span>';
    }

    // Join the elements of the array back into one string, 
    // and use a double line break as the glue
    $content = implode("<br /><br />", $content_array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You need to replace \n with break row tag

Try this

```
echo nl2br($content);
```